# Argument passed in must be a single String of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, rest, objectid

[image]'''   This is my endpoint to delete the task but due to some problem it's not working when i try from postman. When I enter the ID through hard code(statically) its working.
'''

router.delete('/tasks/:id', async (req, res) => {
try {

```
    const task = await Task.findByIdAndDelete(req.params.id) //[![Why my objectid is not valid. It's working fine for other routes ][1]]
    if (!task) {
        res.status(404).send()
    }

    res.send(task)
} catch (e) {
    res.status(500).send()
}
```

})

Comment: Have you printed out the ID to see what it is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use trim method available on strings in javascript you are getting an extra `'\n'` character at the end of your objectId.

```
const {id} = req.params; // destructuring in javascript
 const task = await Task.findByIdAndDelete(id.trim()) // trim the string 
    if (!task) {
        res.status(404).send()
    }
    res.send(task)
} catch (e) {
    res.status(500).send()
}
```

Comment: Thanks Namit for the soloution but can i ask why i am getting an extra '\n' ?